# ASP Clássico em XMLHTTPRquest para o mesmo site

Tags: asp, xmlhttprequest

Olá.

Estou tentando fazer um post de http://java/app/form.asp para http://java/app/notificacao.asp mas está dando timeout com o seguinte código:

```
caminho =  "http://java/app/notificacao.asp"

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.open "POST", caminho, false

objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send    "id=2"

Response.Write objHTTP.responseText
```